# Laplace transform methods for ODEs and PDEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am doing a research project on "*Laplace transform based methods for differential and partial differential equations*". I'm having a hard time finding a few of these "methods". Can someone name a few well known methods?

Comment: When you googled it, what search terms did you use?

Comment: I have googled "Laplace transform methods for differential equations", but I end up finding sites only mentioning "the Laplace Transform method of solving initial value problems", "the Laplace transform method", etc.

Comment: Did you look at [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)?

Comment: The Wikipedia page does not mention any methods for ODEs and PDEs.

Comment: You can start with chapter 7 of "Differential Equations" by H. Edwards and D. Penney.